# php - Add value with key to all the elements

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array which is created by an mysql query result as below:

```
$result = $query->result_array(); 
print_r($result); 

Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [productspec_id] => 40 [data] => ok ) 
[1] => Array ( [productspec_id] => 88 [data] => reasonable  ) 
[2] => Array ( [productspec_id] => 86 [data] => ) 
)
```

I want to append the below two values with key to all the arrays:

```
$inq_id='67';
$prod_id='76';
```

Below is the **expected result** which I need to use to insert into the database:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [productspec_id] => 40 [data] => ok [inq_id] => 67 [prod_id] => 76 ) 
[1] => Array ( [productspec_id] => 88 [data] => reasonable [inq_id] => 67 [prod_id] => 76 ) 
[2] => Array ( [productspec_id] => 86 [data] => [inq_id] => 67 [prod_id] => 76 ) 
)
```

I tried with `array_push` but not working as expected. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map) to compute a new array with the added values for each entry:

```
$result = array_map(
    fn(array $entry): array => $entry + ['inq_id' => 67, 'prod_id' => 76], 
    $result
);
```

Note: PHP 7.4+ syntax.

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/AVm1F)

Alternatively, you could simply loop over your array by [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and alter its entries in place:

```
foreach ($result as &$entry) {
    $entry += ['inq_id' => 67, 'prod_id' => 76];
}
unset($entry);  // Recommended after using a reference pass.
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/CnJ6t)

Not that I used the [`+` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php), which assumes those indices (`inq_id` and `prod_id`) don't already exist in the original array (if they do, they'll take precedence over the new ones). You could alternatively use `array_merge` or push the values individually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain the logic especially the purpose of & symbol before the $entry variable and the unset used.

Comment: If you don't use `&`, the values that the `foreach` loop will iterate over will be *copies* of the original array's entries. Therefore modifying them will have no impact on the original array. Adding `&` tells the loop to pass each entry by reference so that `$entry` points to the original one on each iteration. You should also read the link I added to my answer.